# TigerVNC is running, but not listening on any port?

Tags: vnc, netstat

I'm on CentOS 7 with TigerVNC installed. I have started it up (I think), but I can't connect to it.

Here's what leads me to think it's running:

```
$ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY #   PROCESS ID
:1            29811
```

But `netstat` doesn't list it anywhere:

```
$ netstat -tpln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      957/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1277/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      957/sshd
```

Not sure if it's relevant or not, but here are my `iptables`:

```
$ iptables nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6112 packets, 538K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    6   304 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:5901

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 810 packets, 156K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

(I attempted to add a rule for 5901 thinking that maybe it was related to why I didn't see `vncserver` in `netstat`, but after changing that rule and starting `vncserver`, nothing changed as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vncserver -list` only looks at files in ~/.vnc/.  There should be a file in your ~/.vnc/ directory ending with .pid.  Make sure that the numeric PID in that file (29811) is actually a running process.  It is quite possible that the Xvnc process is not running, but exited in such a way that it didn't clean up the .pid file.  You can also clean it up by running `vncserver -kill :1`.  This will clean up any other socket files that might be remaining.

Comment: Thanks! You were right - the process wasn't actually running. I killed it with `vncserver -kill :1` and then started it again with `vncserver` and this time around, it showed up in `netstat -tpln` (on port 5901) and I was able to connect.